# stack graphs with different temporal resolution in r

Tags: r, ggplot2, graph, stacked

I am trying to stack three graphs using ggplot2 and grid arrange. All three graphs should have have the same x axis (but not sharing), the problem is that all of them are in a different temporal resolution and I am having a hard time to align the axis of the three different plots.

This is what I have:

[image: stacked graphs]

And I want something similar to this:

[image: target format].

Dataset Soil temperature

```
                average
3/1/2018 11:00  9.353692972
3/1/2018 12:00  10.75947564
3/1/2018 13:00  11.56223312
3/1/2018 14:00  11.59511989
3/1/2018 15:00  11.07712308
3/1/2018 16:00  9.762939639
3/1/2018 17:00  7.650089417
3/1/2018 18:00  6.021789611
3/1/2018 19:00  4.844122056
3/1/2018 20:00  3.946675139
3/1/2018 21:00  3.265207733
3/1/2018 22:00  2.751823167
3/1/2018 23:00  2.307551222
3/2/2018 0:00   1.977323322
3/2/2018 1:00   1.714310775
3/2/2018 2:00   1.505199708
3/2/2018 3:00   1.402693267
3/2/2018 4:00   1.384921586
3/2/2018 5:00   1.350009046
....
```

Dataset ppt

```
3/1/2018    0
3/2/2018    0
3/3/2018    0
3/4/2018    0
3/5/2018    0
3/6/2018    0
3/7/2018    0
3/8/2018    0
3/9/2018    0
3/10/2018   0
3/11/2018   0
3/12/2018   0
3/13/2018   0
3/14/2018   0
```

Dataset flux

```
DPF     U       N
7.08    0.00    0.00
14      0.01    0.02
22      0.16    0.25
29.21   0.00    0.00
33.88   0.05    0.00
42.08   0.00    0.00
```

code

```
# define sheets
hourly <- read_excel("ashland2_graphs.xlsx", sheet = 'Hourly')
daily <- read_excel("ashland2_graphs.xlsx", sheet = 'Climate')
nh3flux <-read_excel('ashland2_graphs.xlsx', sheet = 'flux')


# define soil temp
soiltemp <- as.numeric(as.character(hourly$average))

# soil temperature graph
# define x axis
x = c(1:length(soiltemp))

fig1 <- ggplot()+
  geom_line(aes(x=x,y = soiltemp), stat = 'identity') +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(1, length(soiltemp), by = 240), 
                     label = c('0', '10', '20', '30', '40'))

# precipitation graph
ppt <- as.numeric(as.character(daily$ppt))

# precip x axis
x2 = c(1:length(ppt))

fig2 <- ggplot(climate) +
  geom_bar(aes(x = x2, y = ppt), stat = 'identity', color = "grey") +
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0, 0))

print(fig2)

# Losses
urea <- as.numeric(as.character(nh3flux$`NH3 Flux g/m2 day-1 - urea`))
nbpt <- as.numeric(as.character(nh3flux$`NH3 Flux g/m2 day-1 - nbpt`))
x3 <- nh3flux$`Days post fertilization`

fig3 <- ggplot(nh3flux) +
  geom_point(mapping = aes(x = x3, y = urea)) +
  geom_line(mapping = aes(x = x3, y = urea)) +
  geom_point(mapping = aes(x = x3, y = nbpt)) +
  geom_line(mapping = aes(x = x3, y = nbpt), linetype = 'dashed') +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=seq(0, 45, 10), limits = c(0, 45))

print(fig3)

# stack graphs
grid.arrange(fig3, fig2, fig1, ncol = 1)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Setup

For the sake of easy reproducibility, I'll use the `mtcars` dataset to
demonstrate how to tackle this. First let's create our three plots:

```r
library(ggplot2)

set.seed(123)
dfs <- split(mtcars, sample(3, nrow(mtcars), replace = TRUE))

# Three plots, with the same x variable but different y and geoms
p1 <- ggplot(dfs[[1]], aes(wt, mpg)) + geom_point()
p2 <- ggplot(dfs[[2]], aes(wt)) + geom_histogram()
p3 <- ggplot(dfs[[3]], aes(wt, cyl)) + geom_smooth()

plots <- list(p1, p2, p3) # easier to work with them all in a list
```

And here are the plots stacked, exhibiting the same problems that you have:

```r
cowplot::plot_grid(plotlist = plots, ncol = 1)
#> `stat_bin()` using `bins = 30`. Pick better value with `binwidth`.
#> `geom_smooth()` using method = 'loess' and formula 'y ~ x'
```

[image]

(I'm not using `grid.arrange()`, because it lacks some features that we need
for a solution.)

#### Identifying issues

We can identify two problems that need to be taken care of:

1. The x-axis limits need to be equal across the plots.
2. The plot areas need to be aligned. (Varying y-axis label lengths cause
   the plot areas to vary in size.)

#### Solutions

The first problem can be addressed by creating a single coordinate object
defining the x-axis limits that we want. With the plots in a list, it's easy
to apply this coordinate system to each of them with `lapply()`:

```r
common_coord <- coord_cartesian(xlim = c(1.5, 5.5))
common_x_plots <- lapply(plots, `+`, common_coord)
```

For your data, setting the limits to `c(0, 45)` sould do quite nicely.

The second problem is trickier, and I don't think `gridExtra::grid.arrange()`
can solve it without quite a bit of extra work. That's why I would recommend
using `plot_grid()` from the **cowplot** package instead: it has an `align`
option that we can use to line up the plot areas by adding some extra space
between the axis title and axis labels where needed.

#### Result

With both problems adressed, here's the result:

```r
cowplot::plot_grid(plotlist = common_x_plots, ncol = 1, align = "v")
#> `stat_bin()` using `bins = 30`. Pick better value with `binwidth`.
#> `geom_smooth()` using method = 'loess' and formula 'y ~ x'
```

[image]

Following this approach, you should be able to achieve what you're looking for with your real data, too.

Created on 2018-08-24 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0.9000).

Comment: is it possible to save image in high resolution so which can be used for journals ..as I dont want to generate each figure and make panel that part i would like to do it in R itsel..